# Do I have to specify $x \in I$ for this limit?

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Let $a > 0$ and $I = (0,a)$. I want to prove using the definition of limit that $$\lim_{x\to c} x^2 = c^2$$ for all $c \in I$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Since this inequality $|x^2 - c^2| \leq 2a|x - c|$ holds for all $x,c\in I$, I can take $\delta = \varepsilon/(2a)$ as long as $x\in I$. Can I just say that $x \in I$ or  is it better to choose $$\delta = \inf \{c, a - c, \varepsilon/(2a)\}?$$
I have solve the more general problem (that is for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$) with another approach. Just curious for this one.

Comment: It can be useful to refer back to the definition of a limit in cases like this.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying: As $\epsilon$ may be arbitrarily small, we may assume that $\epsilon < \min (a-c, c)$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a value for $\delta$ which satisfy the definition.

I think that $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2a}$ is not a good choice since, for example, for $a=\frac12$ we obtain $\delta = \varepsilon$  which does not satisfy the definition.

Indeed suppose $c=\frac12$ and $x=\frac12+k\varepsilon$ where $k\in(0,1)$, thus:

$$x^2=\frac14+k^2\varepsilon^2+k\varepsilon\implies x^2-\frac14=k^2\varepsilon^2+k\varepsilon=\varepsilon(k^2\varepsilon+k)>1 \quad \forall k\in(k_0,1)$$

The value of $k_0$ can be easily found by the condition

$$k^2\varepsilon+k>1\implies k^2\varepsilon+k-1>0\implies k>k_0=\frac{\sqrt{1+4\varepsilon}-1}{2\varepsilon} $$

[plot of $k_0=\frac{\sqrt{1+4\varepsilon}-1}{2\varepsilon}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(%5Csqrt(1%2B4x)-1)%2F(2x)%20x%3D0..1)

You can proceed as follow.

We need to show that

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists\delta>0 \quad0<|x-c|<\delta\implies|x^2-c^2|<\varepsilon$$

Let consider

$$|x^2-c^2|<\varepsilon\iff-\varepsilon < x^2-c^2< \varepsilon\iff c^2-\varepsilon < x^2< c^2+\varepsilon$$

**Case 1**: $c^2-\varepsilon\leq0$

$$c^2-\varepsilon < x^2< c^2+\varepsilon\iff0<x<\sqrt{c^2+\varepsilon}\iff-c<x-c<\sqrt{c^2+\varepsilon}-c$$
$$\iff|x-c|<\delta=\min\{|c|,\sqrt{c^2+\varepsilon}-c\}$$

**Case 2**: $c^2-\varepsilon>0$

$$c^2-\varepsilon < x^2< c^2+\varepsilon\iff\sqrt{c^2-\varepsilon}<x<\sqrt{c^2+\varepsilon}$$
$$\iff\sqrt{c^2-\varepsilon}-c<x-c<\sqrt{c^2+\varepsilon}-c$$
$$\iff|x-c|<\delta=\min\{c-\sqrt{c^2-\varepsilon},\sqrt{c^2+\varepsilon}-c\}=\sqrt{c^2+\varepsilon}-c$$

Comment: Why it doesn't? $$ 0 < |x - c| < \delta = \varepsilon \implies |x^2 -c^2| \leq 2a|x - c | < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Consider the limit case: $x=c+\varepsilon$ then $x^2-c^2=\varepsilon^2+2\varepsilon c=\varepsilon(\varepsilon+2c)>\varepsilon$

Comment: how can you choose $x = c + \varepsilon$ there? should it be $x < c + \varepsilon$ instead? Which doesn't imply $x^2 - c^2 > \varepsilon$.

Comment: @Azlif Yes I get your point, maybe you are right, let me think better about it!

Comment: @Azlif I confirm my first thought, I've added a full explanation, tell me if it is clear now

Comment: " for example, for $a=\frac 12$ we obtain δ=ε

which does not satisfy the definition.

Indeed suppose $c=\frac 12$".  If $a = \frac 12$ then we can NOT suppose $c = \frac 12$ because $\frac 12 \not \in (0, a) = (0, \frac 12)$.  $c$ must always be strictly less than $a$.

Comment: @fleablood Are you sure?

Comment: Of course, I'm sure.  It distinctly says "**for all c∈I**" and $I = (0,a)$ so $0 < c < a$.  So if $a = \frac 12$ then $c < \frac 12$.

Comment: @fleablood I think we can calculate the limit at $\frac12$ even if $\frac12 \not\in I$. EG $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: So.... ?  The OP isn't asking what the limit at $a$ but the limit of $c$.  It's a bit of a pointless restriction but the point is, so long as $c < a$ then there are $\epsilon < a-c$ and you will not get a contradiction.

Comment: @fleablood Ok I now get your point but I'm not sure that this was the really goal of the OP. Anyway we agree that c is a cluster point of I and we are allowed to calculate the limit in c; in this case the bound given for $\delta$ doen,t work.It could be interesting analize the definition for l<c.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to choose the delta you gave based on $\inf$ (or, equivalently, $\min$, since it's over a finite set), and then show that that implies $x \in I$. Since the domain of the function (seemingly) is $\mathbb{R}$, not $I$, nothing in the definition of the limit guarantees $x \in I$.

(Note that if you had a closed interval $I = [0,a]$, your approach would not work, even though your inequality still holds for all $x,c \in I$! So I think you do have to justify assuming $x \in I$.)